# Querying into CrateDB objects and skip if property not exists

Tags: cratedb

I'm trying to make a query into my CrateDB querying in objects where a property may exist. But I'm having some issues getting a `ColumnUnknownException`.

My query looks quite easy:

```
SELECT "attrs","location" FROM "doc"."raw_foo" WHERE attrs['management_entity'] != "" LIMIT 100;
```

`attrs` column is an object with many attributes and, as I told before, some rows have `management_entity`property.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you also post the schema of the table and the CrateDB version? The query looks correct

Answer (score 0):

Your query should have **single quotes** around not equal operator
`SELECT "attrs","location" FROM "doc"."raw_foo" WHERE attrs['management_entity'] != '' LIMIT 100;`